# Android String variable (HH:mm) to long variable miliseconds

Tags: android, string, time, format, long-integer

I have a String variable in this format `"HH:mm"`.
Lets say the variable value is 05:30.

How would I be able to get those numbers from string and calculate :

(05 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (30 * 60 * 1000) and put that number (miliseconds) in a new long variable.

Basically I need to convert the String time variable into miliseconds long variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `s` contain the string of interest. Then e.g. you can say

```
    String s = "5:30";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+):(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        int hrs = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int min = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
        long ms = (long) hrs * 60 * 60 * 1000 + min * 60 * 1000;
        System.out.println("hrs="+hrs+" min="+min+" ms="+ms);
    } else {
        throw Exception("Bad time format");
    }
```

For what it's worth, there are only 86,400,000 milliseconds in a day, so you don't need the `long`.  An `int` is big enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SimpleDateFormat` class

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

String inputString =  yourTime + ":00.000"; //Added to string to make HH:mm:ss.SSS format

Date date = sdf.parse("1970-01-01 " + inputString);
System.out.println("in milliseconds: " + date.getTime());
```

Comment: By any chance, are you left-handed?  Thanks.

Comment: @Gene Uh, I'm right handed. Can I ask why you'd want to know that?

Comment: I don't mean any disrespect.  A friend has a theory that left-handed and right-handed people have fundamentally different ways of looking at problems. Your solution is so far from the way I looked at this one, I had to test the theory.  I'm right-handed, too.  Guess we're not a proof...  Cheers.

Comment: @Gene No offense taken :-) I proposed this solution because it allows for Times with dates and seconds and milliseconds as well as hours and minutes if the OP ever wants to expand. I prefer future proof solutions, especially when you don't need to work all that much extra when writing the first time.

Comment: Okay. I prefer solutions where the code reads in a way that mirrors its intent.  When I see time zones and a date when I was in junior high school, the problem spec is obscured (at least to me).  If as a maintainer I ever encountered your code, I'd swear under my breath wondering whether you hated me. Sorry.

Comment: @Gene I suppose it varies with experience (FWIW, I'm in high school right now, so I don't really share the time zone feeling).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    simpleDateFormate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String inputString = "05:30";
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = simpleDateFormate.parse( inputString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("in millSeconds: " + date.getTime());  
    long yourvar=date.getTime();
}
```

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)